# Are special functions an active field? A mathematician's dilemma.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, special-functions

Studying analysis, I stumbled upon two branches which I loved: functional analysis and special functions. I began to study q-series and a bit of elliptic functions. However, soon after I talked to some professors, they were very vocal and discouraging. (I study in a university were the main interest in the analysis department is C*-algebras. )

Should I follow their advice and study more modern analysis? Can I research in special functions or is it too hard? Is Watson's coauthored text a good place to continue my study?

Thank you in advance for any advice or suggestion.

Comment: Functional analysis is definitely more widely studied.

Comment: My feeling is that mathematics research should be about finding your own interesting questions to ask and then to set about trying to answer them. If you can't ever find your own original questions to ask, then by definition you have to study the set of existing questions arrived at by others. If you are not motivated by your own topics interest then you have to become fully motivated by other peoples topics of favour. You haven't put a case for anything at all in your question, perhaps you should do something else for a while.

Comment: "special function" is almost any function, so it cannot be a field

Comment: @Masacroso: The term "special function" is another (and often used) term for the [higher transcendental functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=higher+transcendental+functions&filter=0). There is even a [special-functions tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-functions) in MSE, which the OP used in the original version and which was not edited away by a later revision.